# Error 400: Bad Request Aggregate Exception when using Parse Query

Tags: parse-platform, unity-game-engine

I am trying to check if a Parse Object exists on Parse so that I can then either upload a new object for the user if one doesn't exist, or modify the data if one does exist.

The code I am using for this is:

```
if(!FB.IsLoggedIn)
    yield break;
Debug.Log ("NPCF: FB Is Logged In");
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseObject.GetQuery ("User"+FB.UserId);
Debug.Log ("NPCF: Called GetQuery on User" + FB.UserId);

var queryTaskContinueWith = query.FindAsync().ContinueWith( t =>
{
    if(t.IsFaulted)
    {
        using (IEnumerator<System.Exception> enumerator = t.Exception.InnerExceptions.GetEnumerator())
        {
            if (enumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                ParseException error = (ParseException) enumerator.Current;
                Debug.Log ("Error Message: " + error.Message);
                Debug.Log ("Error Code: " + error.Code);
            }
        }
    }
    // NOT REACHING HERE
    Debug.Log ("NPCF: t.Result count: " + t.Result.Count());
    var result = t.Result;

    if(result.Count() == 0)
    {
        //Upload New Data
    }
    else
    {
        //Modify/Sync Data
    }
}
```

I know I've had this working in the past, because I have had  the functionality working completely. Is it actually possible to query an object if the object doesn't exist? Or am I just being stupid right now and missing a step out/forgetting how to properly perform this action?